# Laravel How to not require a required input

Tags: php, html, laravel, forms, web-applications

Hi I have a laravel Webapp (foxtrot invoice management system) in my website, there is required fields in a form that is used to store customer data to create invoice later. I don't want to have all the fields being required. Like, let's say, I want all the field to be optional. How can I do it?

```
<div class="card card-form">
<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-4 card-body">
        <p><strong class="headings-color">{{ __('messages.customer_information') }}</strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted">{{ __('messages.basic_customer_information') }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 card-form__body card-body">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label for="display_name">{{ __('messages.display_name') }}</label>
                    <input name="display_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('messages.display_name') }}" value="{{ $customer->display_name }}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label for="contact_name">{{ __('messages.contact_name') }}</label>
                    <input name="contact_name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('messages.contact_name') }}" value="{{ $customer->contact_name }}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label for="email">{{ __('messages.email') }}</label>
                    <input name="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('messages.email') }}" value="{{ $customer->email }}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="phone">{{ __('messages.phone') }}</label>
                    <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('messages.phone') }}" value="{{ $customer->phone }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label for="currency_id">{{ __('messages.currency') }}</label>
                    <select name="currency_id" data-toggle="select" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="currency_id" required>
                        <option disabled selected>{{ __('messages.select_currency') }}</option>
                        @foreach(get_currencies_select2_array() as $option)
                            <option value="{{ $option['id'] }}" {{ $customer->currency_id == $option['id'] ? 'selected=""' : '' }}>{{ $option['text'] }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="website">{{ __('messages.website') }}</label>
                    <input name="website" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('messages.website') }}" value="{{ $customer->website }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="vat_number">{{ __('messages.vat_number') }}</label>
                    <input name="vat_number" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('messages.vat_number') }}" value="{{ $customer->vat_number }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="kvk_number">{{ __('messages.kvk_number') }}</label>
                    <input name="kvk_number" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('messages.kvk_number') }}" value="{{ $customer->kvk_number }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-4 card-body">
        <p><strong class="headings-color">{{ __('messages.billing_address') }}</strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted">{{ __('messages.customer_billing_address') }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 card-form__body card-body">
        <p class="row"><strong class=" col headings-color">{{ __('messages.billing_address') }}</strong></p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label for="billing[name]">{{ __('messages.name') }}</label>
                    <input name="billing[name]" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="{{ __('messages.address_name') }}" value="{{ $customer->billing->name }}" required>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="billing[phone]">{{ __('messages.phone') }}</label>
                    <input name="billing[phone]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->billing->phone }}" placeholder="{{ __('messages.phone') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    <label for="billing[country_id]">{{ __('messages.country') }}</label>
                    <select id="billing[country_id]" name="billing[country_id]" data-toggle="select" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="billing[country_id]" required>
                        <option disabled selected>{{ __('messages.select_country') }}</option>
                        @foreach(get_countries_select2_array() as $option)
                            <option value="{{ $option['id'] }}" {{ $customer->billing->country_id == $option['id'] ? 'selected=""' : '' }}>{{ $option['text'] }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="billing[state]">{{ __('messages.state') }}</label>
                    <input name="billing[state]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->billing->state }}" placeholder="{{ __('messages.state') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="billing[city]">{{ __('messages.city') }}</label>
                    <input name="billing[city]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->billing->city }}" placeholder="{{ __('messages.city') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="billing[zip]">{{ __('messages.postal_code') }}</label>
                    <input name="billing[zip]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->billing->zip }}" placeholder="{{ __('messages.postal_code') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group required">
            <label for="billing[address_1]">{{ __('messages.address') }}</label>
            <textarea name="billing[address_1]" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="{{ __('messages.address') }}" required>{{ $customer->billing->address_1 }}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

{{-- <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col-lg-4 card-body">
        <p><strong class="headings-color">{{ __('messages.shipping_address') }}</strong></p>
        <p class="text-muted">{{ __('messages.customer_shipping_address') }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-8 card-form__body card-body">
        <p class="row"><strong class=" col headings-color">{{ __('messages.shipping_address') }}</strong></p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="shipping[name]">{{ __('messages.name') }}</label>
                    <input name="shipping[name]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->shipping->name }}" placeholder="{{ __('messages.address_name') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="shipping[phone]">{{ __('messages.phone') }}</label>
                    <input name="shipping[phone]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->shipping->phone }}" placeholder="{{ __('messages.phone') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="shipping[country_id]">{{ __('messages.country') }}</label>
                    <select id="shipping[country_id]" name="shipping[country_id]" data-toggle="select" class="form-control select2-hidden-accessible" data-select2-id="shipping[country_id]">
                        <option disabled selected>{{ __('messages.select_country') }}</option>
                        @foreach(get_countries_select2_array() as $option)
                            <option value="{{ $option['id'] }}" {{ $customer->shipping->country_id == $option['id'] ? 'selected=""' : '' }}>{{ $option['text'] }}</option>
                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="shipping[state]">{{ __('messages.state') }}</label>
                    <input name="shipping[state]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->shipping->state }}" placeholder="{{ __('messages.state') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="shipping[city]">{{ __('messages.city') }}</label>
                    <input name="shipping[city]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->shipping->city }}" placeholder="{{ __('messages.city') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="shipping[zip]">{{ __('messages.postal_code') }}</label>
                    <input name="shipping[zip]" type="text" class="form-control" value="{{ $customer->shipping->zip }}" placeholder="{{ __('messages.postal_code') }}">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="shipping[address_1]">{{ __('messages.address') }}</label>
            <textarea name="shipping[address_1]" class="form-control" rows="2" placeholder="{{ __('messages.address') }}">{{ $customer->shipping->address_1 }}</textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div> --}}

@if($customer->getCustomFields()->count() > 0)
    <div class="row no-gutters">
        <div class="col-lg-4 card-body">
            <p><strong class="headings-color">{{ __('messages.custom_fields') }}</strong></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-8 card-form__body card-body">
            <div class="row">
                @foreach ($customer->getCustomFields() as $custom_field)
                    @include('layouts._custom_field', ['model' => $customer, 'custom_field' => $custom_field])
                @endforeach
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endif
```

{{ __('messages.save_customer') }}

Comment: removing the `required` property in the inputs should work for frontend. Share the request validation if you need help for backend

Comment: thnx Jack this was helpful